# Modified Skip32 to generate only obfuscated postive int in java?

Tags: java, encryption, obfuscation, bitwise-operators, block-cipher

The following implementation of Skip32 for java produces signed int([Skip32 impementation](https://github.com/boivie/skip32-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/boivie/skip32/Skip32.java)).

Is there way to modify it so that only positive numbers are generated ?

Or can one use the absolute value of the int generated(without worrying about duplicity ) ?

Comment: Is zero allowed, or do you only want to allow _strictly_ positive numbers?

Comment: @LouisWasserman i want strictly positive numbers as i want to use them as reference id

Comment: The simplest way to make the output positive is to store it in a long, e.g. `long val = skip32(x) & 0xffffffffL;` Note that skip32 is a *permutation*. It maps a 32-bit input into a 32-bit output such that skip32(x) = skip32(y) if and only if x = y. It is not at all clear what your input to this function is.